# Extracting dynamically constructed strings in IDA

Tags: ida

Sometimes strings are dynamically constructed in programs due to compiler optimization or simply to hide the strings (e.g. in malware). For example :

[image]

When displaying the bytes as chars we can see the string `'INVALID FILE SIZE'`.

[image]

Does anyone know a script to extract those strings in IDA? I will write one if it does not exist but I figured I would ask first.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question, my google skills failed me this time. Thanks for the answers, the script ASERT does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Select the block of code you would like to convert and then run the following IDAPython function. Comment out the call to MakeComm if you don't want a comment added.

```
def convert_to_char():
    current = SelStart()
    end = SelEnd()
    tmp = ''
    while current < end:
        OpChr(current,1)
        try:
            tmp += chr(GetOperandValue(current, 1))
        except:
            tmp += '_'
        current = NextHead(current)
    MakeComm(PrevHead(current), tmp)
```

Adding some logic to verify the operand might be useful if other instruction are also in the selected region.

Answer (score 3):

[Finding Byte Strings Using IDAPython](http://www.arbornetworks.com/asert/2013/07/asert-mindshare-finding-byte-strings-using-idapython/)

This is exactly what you were looking for from Assert MindshaRE
Effectively this script will go through instruction by instruction to find moves of ASCII characters into a memory location. It gets fancy and used QT to create an interactive table however you can gut out that part and just have it place a comment at the instruction that gets used.